# Make faster videocapture opencv

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

So I create a Neural Network(CNN) that can predict in real-time using opencv the gender of a person, everything works perfect, but, when I run the code OpenCv has so much lag, my webcam is not that bad, here is my code

```
    '''
Real-time Face Gender Recognition using Conv-Nueral Network (CNN) and Cv2

Here we predict the save model that it is train
'''
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import cvlib as cv
import imutils

# load the model
model = load_model('gender_detection.model')

# open webcams and initiate the camara
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

classes = ['hombre', 'mujer']

# loop through frames
while webcam.isOpened():
    # read frame from webcam
    status, frame = webcam.read()
    #webcam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 1000)
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    # apply face detection
    face, confidence = cv.detect_face(frame) # this detects that there is a face in the camara, cvlib does, but not if it is a man that detects the neural network

    # loop through detected faces
    for idx, f in enumerate(face):
        # get corner points of face rectangle
        # this only will draw a rectangle when the cvlib detects the face with the vars giving up there
        startX, startY = f[0], f[1]
        endX, endY = f[2], f[3]

        # draw the rectangle over the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0,255,0), 2)

        # crop the detected face region
        face_crop = np.copy(frame[startY:endY, startX:endX])

        if face_crop.shape[0] < 10 or face_crop.shape[1] < 10:
            continue

        # preprocessing for gender detection model
        face_crop = cv2.resize(face_crop, (96,96))
        face_crop = face_crop.astype("float") / 255.0
        face_crop = img_to_array(face_crop)
        face_crop = np.expand_dims(face_crop, axis=0)

        # apply gender detection face with the model
        conf = model.predict(face_crop)[0]

        # get label with max acc
        idx = np.argmax(conf)
        label = classes[idx]

        label = "{}: {:.2f}".format(label, conf[idx] * 100)

        Y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10

        # write label and confidence above the face rectangle
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, Y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    0.7, (0,255,0), 2)

    # display output
    cv2.imshow("Gender Detection", frame)

    # press "Q" to stop
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


#realese resources
webcam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and I also tried to use cv2.CAP_PROB_FPS but that only helps a little bit, not much.

Comment: how much time does inference take?

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz how can i check that, or what is that?

Comment: Fetch `time.time()` at various places in the code so you can see how long each step takes.  I'm guessing the facial recognition is where your time happens

Comment: @TimRoberts I try it, and in all parts is the same, but when the green square of my face dont appear (cover my face) in the opencv it goes faster, not very very fast but faster

Comment: 2 wffectstcan happen: 1. your processing is slow (you cant remove that if yoz need the processing). 2. your processing is slow AND videocapture delivers old frames.. You can improve that by multi-threading the capturing and only deliver the latest frame to the processing. The problem here is: If camera for example delivers  25 fps and videocapture has a buffer of 4 frames and processing has 1 fps, you will get a delay of 4 seconds instead of 1 second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this same problem using openCV video capture with text-detection. It's not the webcam quality, but the fact that openCV can only show you frames as fast as you can process them in your gender detection. The solution that worked for me is to use multi-threading.

You can create a thread for the OpenCV video capture, then another thread for your image processing. The caveat: you can't magically make your image processing happen quicker without making changes the image process itself. It takes as long as it takes. What you can do is allow openCV to work on its own and send the frames to an exchange class, then allow the image processing to grab a frame and work at its own pace as CV2 continues as normal.

Here is a (shortened) version of my class for OCR image processing. You can see that in start() i'm creating a thread pointed at the ocr() process. This is where your gender identification process can go.

```
class OCR:

    # def __init__(self, exchange: VideoStream, language=None):
    def __init__(self):
        self.exchange = None
        # init stuff for OCR not relevant to my example, but note that it 
        # takes a VideoStream class called exchange which is where this class 
        # grabs frames to process

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.ocr, args=()).start()
        return self

    def set_exchange(self, video_stream):
        self.exchange = video_stream

    def ocr(self):

        while not self.stopped:
            if self.exchange is not None:
                frame = self.exchange.frame

                # # # OCR stuff goes here
```

Now here is the VideoStream class that grabs frames at its own pace, in a different thread. The image processing class (OCR) can then take these frames at it's own pace and the two don't affect each other's performance.

```
class VideoStream:
    """Class for CV2 video capture. The start() method will create a new 
thread to read the video stream"""
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
        # self._boxes = None
        self.stopped = False

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.get, args=()).start()
        return self

    def get(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

    def get_video_dimensions(self):
        width = self.stream.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        height = self.stream.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        return int(width), int(height)

    def stop_process(self):
        self.stopped = True
```

Then you can do your CV2 imshow loop as you normally would.

```
exchange = VideoStream(0).start()
ocr = OCR().start()
ocr.set_exchange(exchange)

 while True:  # Begins a loop for the real-time OCR display
        pressed_key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if pressed_key == ord('q'):
            stop_stream_ocr(exchange, ocr)
            break

        frame = exchange.frame 

        cv2.imshow("Video Get Frame", frame)
        cps1.increment()
```

Note that you can't really control what thread CV2 decides to use in its internal workings, but this approach will allow you to display your webcam at its natural fps and while image processing happens in the background.

Comment: Hi, i think this is the solution, but how can i apply that to my code?

Comment: You can can separate your code into classes like I showed. One class will be for the gender recognition being performed on a CV2 frame, which I called OCR because that was what I was doing when I wrote this. A second class will be for video capture, which shouldn't differ too much in your case. Then you can tie the two processes together in the main loop like I showed at the bottom.

Comment: ... It is a little daunting if you've never used multi-threading with classes before. I'm planning on putting all this code on github very soon (in the next day or two) and hopefully you can run it and reverse engineer most of it for your own use.

Comment: I will do it and then i will edit my question with the new code only if it doesnt work

Comment: Yeah not really sure why the question is downvoted. It's a really common problem people have with CV2 imshow() and the solution isn't exactly obvious.

Comment: @rapsberry_next hey, i already code it but is not working, can you help me?, I already ask a question here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67010610/multi-threading-what-is-wrong-with-my-code> there is the code

Comment: @Rodrigo answered there. I can't really get to the heart of it without setting up your project on my machine. If you want to post it on github, I'd be happy to make a push request if I can fix it.

Comment: I already post my code on github, take a look, is not neccesary to train the model, is already trained https://github.com/BernardoOlisan/Gender-Recognition.git