# multi-threading, what is wrong with my code

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

I was trying to make faster my frames in opencv, it was so slow using it normal, so I decided to ask it here [Make faster videocapture opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993242/make-faster-videocapture-opencv/66993631?noredirect=1#comment118424133_66993631) the answer was to use multi threading to make it faster, so I code it like this

```
    # The same genderrecognition.py code but with multi-threading to make it faster and fix the the lag of the other one
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import cvlib as cv

# open webcam and initiate the cam
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)


# opencv class
class VideoStream:
    def __init__(self):
        # read frame from webcam
        self.status, self.frame = webcam.read()
        webcam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 1000)
        self.frame = cv2.flip(self.frame, 1)

        print("videostream working")


# face detection class
class face_detection:
    def __init__(self):
        # use VideoStream Class variables
        self.videostream = VideoStream()
        self.frame = self.videostream.frame

        # apply face detection
        self.face, self.confidence = cv.detect_face(self.frame)

        # loop through detected faces
        for self.idx, self.f in enumerate(self.face):
            # get the corner point of the rectangle
            self.startX, self.startY = self.f[0], self.f[1]
            self.endX, self.endY = self.f[2], self.f[3]

            cv2.rectangle(self.frame, (self.startX, self.startY), (self.endX, self.endY), (0,255,0), 2)
            self.face_crop = np.copy(self.frame[self.startY:self.endY, self.startX:self.endX])

            if self.face_crop.shape[0] < 10 or self.face_crop.shape[1] < 10:
                continue

            # preprocessing for gender detection model
            self.face_crop = cv2.resize(self.face_crop, (96,96))
            self.face_crop = self.face_crop.astype("float") / 255.0
            self.face_crop = img_to_array(self.face_crop)
            self.face_crop = np.expand_dims(self.face_crop, axis=0)

            GFR()
        print("face_detection working")

# gender recognition class
class GFR:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = load_model("C:/Users/berna/Desktop/Programming/AI_ML_DL/Projects/FaceGenderRecognition/gender_detection.model")
        self.facedetection = face_detection()

        self.face_crop = self.facedetection.face_crop
        self.classes = ['hombre', 'mujer']
        self.startX, self.startY = self.facedetection.startX, self.facedetection.startY
        self.endX, self.endY = self.facedetection.endX, self.facedetection.endY
        self.frame = self.facedetection.frame

        # apply the gender detection face with the model
        self.conf = model.predict(self.face_crop)[0]

        # get label with max acc
        self.idx = np.argmax(self.conf)
        self.label = self.classes[self.idx]

        self.label = "{}: {:.2f}".format(self.label, self.conf[self.idx] * 100)

        self.Y = self.startY - 10 if self.startY - 10 > 10 else self.startY + 10

        # write label and confidence above the face rectangle
        cv2.putText(self.frame, self.label, (self.startX, self.Y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    0.7, (0,255,0), 2)

        print("gender recognition working!")


# classes and webcam while loop
gender_detection = GFR()


# loop through frames
while webcam.isOpened():
    VideoStream()
    face_detection()

    # display output
    cv2.imshow("Gender Detection", gender_detection.frame)

    # press "Q" to stop
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

webcam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it give me no errors, but compared to my other code that is on the other question, the webcam open and on this one no, any idea?

Comment: @raspberry_next maybe you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VideoStream class's init looks ok, but I think you might have better luck creating a cv2 VideoCapture object in the init as well:

```
self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

I'm not really as familiar with webcam.set() but if you want to incorporate that, I'm sure you can.

Here you have grabbed the initial frames:

```
self.status, self.frame = webcam.read()
```

(Or using the new self.stream variable):

```
self.status, self.frame = self.stream.read()
```

Yet this will only grab a frame when it's initialized, not in a loop. To achieve a loop, you have to make a few more class methods. One will be for continuously getting frames (I added a self.stopped attribute, although it's not in your code. It might be a good idea to have a True/False stop flag):

```
def read_stream(self):
    while not self.stopped:
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
```

Then if you want to use multithreading, you can make a thread pointing to the read_stream method:

```
def start(self):
    Thread(target=self.read_stream, args=()).start()
    return self
```

You will have to call the start() method on the VideoStream before you start your CV2 imshow() loop.

```
video_stream = VideoStream().start().  #<------Here--------

while webcam.isOpened():
    
    face_detection()

    # display output
    cv2.imshow("Gender Detection", gender_detection.frame)

    # press "Q" to stop
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Hopefully this helps getting the CV2 display to show. Whether your GFR class or face detection is grabbing the right frames from the VideoStream class... that's something else, and I can't debug all that code.

Comment: alright, I think im getting to understand this, but yes im going to post the whole projects on github for you to debug it, you will not have to run the train.py file bc is already train and save in .model file, lemme submit it i will give it to you here

Comment: and sorry if my questions sounds like a beginner, but I know Machine learning and Deep, but in using opencv, im a complete beginner

Comment: here it is https://github.com/BernardoOlisan/Gender-Recognition.git let me know if u could use it

Comment: I'm not as familiar with ML and tensorflow. So I get this error, do you know how to fix it?

"Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /Gender-Recognition/gender_detection.model/variables/variables"

Comment: Got the webcam and facial detection to work in the new gr_faster.py:  https://github.com/nathanaday/Gender-Recognition/tree/Fix

Comment: dude, sorry for the delay, and thats right, your new code make the webcam faster! you are fire. the only thing is the gender recognition didnt work but thats alright i can fix it, you told me you got "Failed to find any matching files for /Gender-Recognition/gender_detection.model/variables/variables", yeah, it was bc in the .model folder I forgot to add some other, but thanks bro a lot! and it would be nice if you explain me the changes u made!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I'm putting my OCR on github and writing the README right now. It's essentially the same process--replace OCR with Gender Detection. Hopefully you can read those docs and see what I did in your code.

Comment: As promised: the code...

https://github.com/nathanaday/RealTime-OCR