# Why does opencv-python take 4 to 5 seconds in VideoCapture(0) to open the camera and view screen

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I have a fairly simple code which detects faces by CascadeClassifier

```
import cv2
photo_face = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
while True:
    _, frame = photo_face.read()
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_frame)
    for x, y, w, h in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('recognize_face', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
        break
```

But the videocamera takes around 4 to 5 seconds to open the camera. I know that any other code is not taking time as I have tried removing it. I tried removing the whole while loop and cascade opening and just did a print statement after `photo_face = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` but even then it takes 4 to 5 seconds to print yes

Comment: And your problem is? The communication with the video device must be established - it is a one time cost. If you need it faster, start your script earlier? Get the first frame first thing in the script and ignore the returns

Comment: @PatrickArtner sorry I couldn't understand what you meant, I am fairly new to opencv. Do you mean should I do the code _, frame = photo_face.read() before the cascade opening line once and than at the end of while loop too, then that is not working

Comment: You could try it - no idea if it helps. Otherwise maybe you want seperate threads for video capture and your detect code - maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993242/make-faster-videocapture-opencv helps

Comment: @PatrickArtner using VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) helped a little and has brought down the delay to 1 to 2 seconds but it is still there

Comment: what you're asking is impossible. it will always take some time to initialize a camera.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz okay I thought it was some code problem thanks

Comment: I test it and it worked right away. No delay.